# Net core blazor is displayed only on the first click after clicking the menu (a tag) and passing the value to another page

Tags: asp.net

Click on the menu (TAB a) to transfer the value to other pages, only the first click will display and then click on the other menu contents remain unchanged

The problem:"products/showproduct/@secitem.Id"  Can I do that

```
<li><a href="@item.Url/@item.Id" title="@item.MenuName">@item.MenuName</a></li>

@code {

    private IList<CmsNavMenu> cmsNavMenu = new List<CmsNavMenu>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        cmsNavMenu = await cmsNavMenuService.GetList();

    }  
}
```

Address changed when clicking menu,But the content has not changed:

https://localhost:44384/AboutUs/AboutUs/939561827476439040
https://localhost:44384/AboutUs/Certificate/939561827476439046

Page receive parameter:

```
    @page "/AboutUs/Aboutus/{Id}"
    @code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
         aboutus = await cmsArticleService.GetAboutUs(Id);
         Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aboutus);
    }
   }

@page "/AboutUs/certificate/{Id}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private dynamic aboutus;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        aboutus = await cmsArticleService.GetAboutUs(Id);
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aboutus);
    }
}

public Task<dynamic> GetAboutUs(string id)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {  
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CmsContext>();
                DapperContext dapperContext = new DapperContext(context); 
                string sql = "select a.Title,a.ImgUrl,a.ArticleContent,nm.Url,nm.MenuName,nm.Id as NavId from CmsArticle a left join CmsNavMenu nm on a.NavMenuId = nm.Id where a.Deleted='" + false + "' and NavMenuId='" + id + "'";

                var aboutus = dapperContext.Query<dynamic>(sql).FirstOrDefault();

                return Task.FromResult(aboutus);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct, are you having a specific problem or are you just asking? Have you actually tried to run that code?

Comment: Tried and failed to run with error

Comment: Can you post the error then please??

Comment: The problem I had was that the Id was passed in when I clicked on the menu and only the first click showed the data content and then when I clicked on the other menu the address changed but the content didn't change

Comment: Can you log `cmsArticleService.GetAboutUs(Id)` response ? `Console.WrtieLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(aboutus))`

Comment: An error occurred while clicking on the menu:There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'.

Comment: JsonSerializer.Serialize(aboutus) error： "Serializes" method without using a parameter overloading

Comment: But I use Newtonsoft. Json. JsonConvert. SerializeObject resolved or errors but normal display data